# parsing if / else / if statements

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to replicate the structure of a simple if statement:

```
if (paren) { block } [else ({ block } | rec if (paren)) ]
```

for if (paren) block, I create a IfBlock AST node. Otherwise, it recursively fills a IfElseBlock node.

I've tried quite a few alternate constructions

```
let parse_if = 
    suffixparen .>>. suffixblock |>> IfBlock 
    //>>? attempt (str "else" >>. ifParser) |>> IfElseBlock 
    //<|> preturn IfBlock
    // .>>? attempt (str "else" >>. ifParser) |>> IfElseBlock
    // suffixparen .>>. suffixblock |>> IfBlock 
    // <|> ifParser |>> IfElseBlock

let inlineIf = str_ws "if" >>. parse_if
do ifParserR := inlineIf
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you had a look at my GLSL parser (it's a C-like language)?
http://laurent.le-brun.eu/fsharp/glsl_parse.fs

From the code example, here is the relevant part for the `if` statement:

```
let statement, stmtRef = createParserForwardedToRef()

let ifStatement =
    pipe3 (keyword "if" >>. parenExp) statement (opt (keyword "else" >>. statement))
      (fun cond stmt1 stmt2 -> Ast.If(cond, stmt1, stmt2))

stmtRef := choice [
  simpleStatement
  block
  ifStatement
  forLoop
  //...
  ]
```

I think your problem is that you're using `attempt` instead of `opt`. `opt` means the `else` part is optional (if it's not there, you get `None`). `attempt` is quite different:

> The parser `attempt p` applies the
>   parser `p`. If `p` fails after changing
>   the parser state or with a fatal
>   error, `attempt p` will backtrack to the
>   original parser state and report a
>   non‐fatal error.

When the parser in `attempt` fails, there's still an error but the input is not consumed (it's useful when combined with the `<|>` or `choice` operators).

Comment: Thanks Laurent. For the records, I've also tried to combine attempt and <|>% None with no avail.